# Security concerns of using mongodb

Tags: security, mongodb

I come from mysql background, and I am aware of typical security concerns when using mysql.

Now, I am using mongodb (java driver).

What are the security concerns, and what are possible ways of avoiding security problems?

Specifically these areas:

1) Do I need to do anything for each get/post?

2) I store cookies from my application on client side and read those later (currently the only information I store is user's location, no sensitive information), Anything I should be careful about?

3) I have text boxes, text areas in my forms which users submit. Do I need to check for anything before saving data in mongo?

Can anybody provide any instances of security problems with existing applications in production?

Comment: Look at this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security/#interfaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Regarding programming:

When you come from a mysql background, you are surely thinking about SQL Injections and wonder if there is something like that for MongoDB.

When you make the same mistake of generating commands as strings and then sending them to the database by using [db.command(String)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DB.html#command%28java.lang.String%29), you will have the same security problems. But no MongoDB tutorial I have ever read even mentions this method.

When you follow the usually taught practice of building DBObjects and passing them to the appropriate methods like collection.find and collection.update, it's the same as using parameterized queries in mysql and thus protects you from most injection attempts.

### Regarding configuration:

You need, of course, make sure that the database itself is configured properly to not allow unauthorized access. Note that the out-of-the-box configuration of MongoDB is usually **not safe**, because it allows non-authorized access from anywhere. Either enable authentication, or make sure that your network firewalls are configured to only allow access to the mongodb port from within the network. But this is a topic for [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 4):

It is in fact possible to perform injections with Mongo. My experience with it is in Ruby, but consider the following:

```
Request: /foo?id=1234
id = query_param["id"]
collection.find({_id: id})
# collection.find({_id: 1234})
```

Seems innocuous enough, right? Depending on your HTTP library, though, you may end up parsing certain query strings as data structures:

```
Request: /foo?id[$gt]=0
# query_param["id"] => {"$gt": 0}
collection.find({_id: id})
# collection.find({_id: {"$gt": 0}})
```

This is likely less of a danger in strongly typed languages, but it's still a concern to watch out for.

The typical rememdy here is to ensure that you always cast your inbound parameter data to the type you expect it to be, and fail hard when you mismatch types. This applies to cookie data, as well as any other data from untrusted sources; aggressive casting will prevent a clever user from modifying your query by passing in operator hashes in stead of a value.

The [MongoDB documentation similarly says](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#dollar-sign-operator-escaping):

> Field names in MongoDB’s query language have semantic meaning. The dollar sign (i.e $) is a reserved character used to represent operators (i.e. $inc.) Thus, you should ensure that your application’s users cannot inject operators into their inputs.

You might also get some value out of [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23734/what-type-of-attacks-can-be-used-vs-mongodb).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Noted: Failing hard when input parameters have unwanted reserved characters like $ used to represent operators.

Comment: You don't want to just fail if you get a `$`, only if you get a hash key starting with one. :)

Comment: :) ya Chris, I thought that goes without saying